# is there any way where I can find out when was the last time a String/Integer was accessed in Java?

Tags: java, string, session, timestamp, pooling

I have sessionID stored in String and I want to keep a timer for it if its idle for 5 minutes, I want to close the session. 
session is created in different jar, that is third party app. Which cannot be edited. It is just returning session ID to my Api.

All I can do is with the session id I have. 
I am trying to pool the session. We are using Jre 1.7

If, I cannot get time-stamp of a string that is accessed last time. Then Can I store that string in a Map/List and get the time-stamp of that string last time it was accessed ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with your own class *Session*:

```
public class Session {
  private String sessionId;
  private long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() \ 1000;
  private long duration = 60 * 5;

  public Session(String sessionId) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
  }

  public boolean isOutOfTime() {
     if (this.timestamp + duration < System.currentTimeMillis() \ 1000) {
       return false;
     } else {
       return true;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such attribute/member in the String class for ***lastTimeAccess***,

your guess is right, you will need to define/implement your custom.

```
Map<String,Long>
```

where you CAREFULLY will need to take care of immutable characteristic in the string object

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing within the *standard* java libraries to support this; you would have to build your own "Wrapper" class; and cache infrastructure around that. And don't be mistaken: getting that **correct** can turn out to be an **advanced** task!

Thus I would be really careful about doing this *yourself*. This is an advanced topic, and my advise: look for existing frameworks that already do that for you, like [ehcachee](http://www.ehcache.org/).

Seriously: be careful about re-inventing the wheel here.